# GLKView : Trouble with offscreen RenderBuffer with Core Animation Layer

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I am trying to attach a renderbuffer following Apples guide [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html).

My problem is that if try to I create the FBO this way, 2 scenarios happen :

a) If I draw any thing or call `self.bindDrawable()` prior to `renderbufferStorage(_:_:)`, `renderbufferStorage` will return `false`, so the whole thing fails

b) If I run the two functions below before I call `bindDrawable` or draw anything, the renderbuffer will be successfully created, but I will get this error when I try to draw :

> Failed to bind EAGLDrawable:  to GL_RENDERBUFFER 2
>   Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6

```
private func initFrameBuffer() -> GLuint {
    var framebuffer_id: GLuint = 0
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_id)
    glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), framebuffer_id)
    return framebuffer_id
}

private func initRenderBuffer() -> GLuint {
    var renderBuffer_id: GLuint = 0
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer_id);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), renderBuffer_id);
    let status = context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), from: layer as! CAEAGLLayer)
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), renderBuffer_id)
    return renderBuffer_id
}
```

I sat up my GLKView as such :

```
    context               = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES3)
    drawableColorFormat   = .RGBA8888
```